# Pre-render a static website from REST-api and templates?

Tags: node.js, rest, static, frontend

I have a rest-api that I will use to render html using some basic templating language. I wonder if there is any good platform or service for pre-rendering HTML-files and serv them statically. For performance and scalability.

I need to pre render the pages contiously, like every 24 hours, and it should also be possible to tell the system to re-render a specific page somehow. I'm comfortable in most open-source languages, node is a favourite.

Comment: Are all the HTML pages cross-linked? In other words, is it possible to load the "home" index.html page and crawl the entire site by following hyperlinks?

Comment: Yes, but I will also provide a sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the most straightforward way to accomplish this is to use two tiers: a rendering server and a cache server. When cache server starts up it would crawl through every url on the rendering server and store the pre-rendered HTMLS files into its local directory. For simplicity you can mirror the "directory structure" and make the resource paths identical. In other words, for every URL on the rendering server that looks like this:

```
http://render.xyz/path/to/resource
```

You create a directory structure `/path/to` on the cache server and put a file `resource` in it.

Your end-users don't need to be aware of this architecture. They make requests to the cache server like this:

```
http://cache.xyz/path/to/resource
```

The cache server gives them the result they are looking for.

There are many ways to tell the cache server to refresh (re-generate) a page. You could add a "hidden" directory, let's call it `.cache-command`, and use it to handle refresh requests. For example, to tell the cache server to refresh a resource, you would use a URL like this:

```
http://cache.xyz/.cache-command/refresh/path/to/resource
```

When the cache server received that request, it would refresh the resource.

One of the advantages of this approach is that your cache server can be completely independent of the render server. They could be written in different languages, running on different hardware, or they could be part of the same nodejs application. Whatever works best for you.